# Bukkit - Change the speed of a projectile

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm pretty new to bukkit plugin developing and I was wondering how I would change the speed of a snowball/any other projectile. In my code, when a player interacts with a certain object it will fire a snowball but I need to change the speed of it. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (!(event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)) return;
    if (!(event.getItem().getType() == Material.BLAZE_ROD)) return;
    Snowball snowball = player.launchProjectile(Snowball.class);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a segment of your code in order for people to help you.

Comment: You can find the code here:
http://pastebin.com/TbV08Tij

Comment: That code is insufficient. Where's the code for Snowball, where you'll presumably find setSpeed() and getSpeed() methods?

Comment: I'm assuming the `Snowball` class is a derivative of the `Bukkit` `Projectile` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are only simply launching the `Snowball` projectile. You have to add velocity to the object to change its speed. This is done by editing the object itself.

Here's the basic outline that you should use. I have no means to test this, but it should help to point you in the right direction.

```
Snowball snowball = player.launchProjectile(Snowball.class);

// Get vectors
Vector i = target.getLocation().toVector();
Vector j = snowball.getLocation().toVector();

// Perform the subtraction, then normalize
Vector r = i.subtract(j);
Vector v = r.normalize();

// then, actually set the speed, in this case, by a magnitude of four
Vector velocity = v.multiply(4);

// Then, set the velocity of the snowball but updating the 'default' velocity of the snowball
snowball.setVelocity(snowball.setVelocity(velocity));
```

This could be condensed by writing the compound expression:

```
Snowball snowball = player.launchProjectile(Snowball.class);

Vector velocity = (target.getLocation().toVector().subtract(snowball.getLocation().toVector()).normalize()).multiply(4);
snowball.setVelocity(snowball.setVelocity(velocity));
```

Hope this helps!